# deploy cocos2dx existing ios project for android platform

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x project in ios platform and I want to deploy this project in android as well.Please help me and explain the steps for it.My cocos2d-x project contains Box2d features into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a sample project for the Android using cocos command and then need to configure some basic parameters. Check out wiki linked on official site .

https://github.com/chukong/cocos-docs/blob/master/manual/framework/native/getting-started/v3.0/how-to-start-a-new-game/en.md

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the existing ios project, how can I deploy that in android platform.